# Has the Stern-Gerlach experiment now been carried out with free electrons or protons instead of silver atoms?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, electrons, quantum-spin, magnetic-moment

At least, why not try with protons, they are much heavier and at the end, any deflection from Lorentz force will not overshadow the Stern- Gerlach phenomenon.

But the question is still, was such experiment carried out or not?

Comment: I don’t know the answer, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern–Gerlach_experiment) says: “The experiment is normally conducted using electrically neutral particles such as silver atoms. This avoids the large deflection in the path of a charged particle moving through a magnetic field and allows spin-dependent effects to dominate.”

Comment: Will neutrons do - https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0022-3735/13/2/025

Comment: Here is the measurement of the proton magnetic moment performed by Rabi et al in 1934: https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.46.157